# Add default date to ionic-datetime - ionic 4 angular project

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am having some hard time setting default date on ionic-4, basically I've tried other approaches that used to work in previous versions already but something changed and they aren't working.

html:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label position="floating" color="primary">Date</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime class="nutri-primary" color="primary" [(ngModel)]="date" display-format="MMM DD, YYYY HH:mm"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

In my page.ts file:

```
private date;
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.date = moment().toISOString();
}
```

The field display without a default date, it's possible to pick a date and it's properly accessible in typescript. The issue is that when entering the page the default date(now) that I would like to display is not there.

My deps:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "^7.2.2",
"@angular/core": "^7.2.2",
"@angular/forms": "^7.2.2",
"@angular/http": "^7.2.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.2",
"@angular/router": "^7.2.2",
"@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic-native/sqlite": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic/angular": "^4.0.0",
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try writing code as shown below

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>MM DD YY</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime id="dynamicDisabled" displayFormat="MM DD YY" value="1994-12-15"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Thank you, but that's not what I need. I need to bind it and different format.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, I was missing the name attribute on the ion-datetime(name="date"), I believe it's required due to the item being inside a form tag. Once I added it it worked.

html:

```
<ion-item>
<ion-label position="floating" color="primary">Date</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime name="date" class="nutri-primary" color="primary" [(ngModel)]="date" display-format="MMM DD, YYYY HH:mm"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```